# How to select which graphics card to use?

Tags: linux, graphics

I have a desktop machine (running Ubuntu 13.10) with two video outputs (both nVidia):

1. an integrated graphics card, which I want to use for my desktop display, and
2. a PCI graphics card, which I would like to use for CUDA based tasks.

Is there a way to select which one to use for the X server and which for CUDA, and make it permanent?

Comment: Which Linux distribution? What model of GPUs?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 and they are both Nvidia

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can follow the directions outlined here in this post titled: [Multiple Nvidia Video Cards & Monitors on Linux Mint 15 MATE](http://www.mysolutions.it/multiple-nvidia-video-cards-monitors-linux-mint-15-mate/). Even though the details are targeting Linux Mint they should still be applicable, since the bulk of the tweaking is being done through the NVIDIA drivers.

I would assume that you can do so either through the NVIDIA dialogs or through your `xorg.conf` file.

*dialogs*

[image: ss #1]

*xorg.conf files*

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 6200"
    BusID          "PCI:5:4:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection
```

Then just only assign the displays to the internal "device":

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This is just to give you the general approach, see the article for further details.

Comment: Hey, that's my article!  I'm famous, woo!  :D

Amazing what you find when you look through the referrer logs for the day, eh?

Comment: @Logos - very nicely constructed article! Thanks for posting it.

Comment: The link is dead.  Long live the wayback machine!  https://web.archive.org/web/20140922055121/http://www.mysolutions.it/multiple-nvidia-video-cards-monitors-linux-mint-15-mate