# How to switch between GPUs on Mint 17.2 ASUS laptop?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, gpu, intel-graphics

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M and Intel HD Graphics 4600. In CS:GO I have frame-drops constantly, it jumps all the time between 5 and 40 fps - this makes game unplayable. And on 960m it should work somehow better. So I think it's a problem with using wrong gpu.

Comment: Have you tried [this solution?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116598/how-to-select-which-graphics-card-to-use)

Comment: @MatthewRock I've seen similar solutions, but my settings were empty. However, I had to change driver in system drivers settings to nvidia driver and restart computer. Now it seems to be working. Around 100-120fps.  For now its enough, but I will later try to improve some things in that matter. Anyway. Thanks for help :)

Comment: congratulations! Consider answering your own question and accepting it later, so that others who encounter similar problem might find solution.